# Firebase Dynamic Linking On Custom Email Domains

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, digital-signature, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a react-native app which utilizes firebase's dynamic link and sends sign in link to emails of the user. What I have noticed is if the user uses a gmail account, the user gets redirected to the app instantly and he signs in. However, when the user is using another domain such as abc@nyu.edu, they are redirected to the browser where they get a prompt Open in app. Does anyone know about this ?

I checked all the action code settings of the dynamic links. handleCodeInApp is set to true, and all the properties in firebase are set to redirect the user back to the app directly. I want to have a consistent behaviour with gmail account and any other domain accounts by redirecting the user straight to the app.